# Creating an array list but having an issue in my switch statement involving modifyfruit

Tags: java

For some reason I am getting a error in my switch statement saying that the parameters I input are not created. All of my methods are correct but I am not seeing where the issue is. Can anyone help me out with this?

```
package javaapplication7;

import com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.RETURN;
import java.awt.Event;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.jar.Attributes;


public class JavaApplication7 {
    private static ArrayList<String> charles = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static Scanner chris = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static boolean loops = true;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        charles.add("Apple");
        charles.add("Orange");
        charles.add("Grapes");
        charles.add("Plums");
        charles.add("Grapefruit");
        charles.add("Kiwi");
        System.out.println("ArrayList Addons");
        System.out.println("==================");
        System.out.println(charles);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Choose a number");

        while(loops){

           System.out.println("Enter Select A Choice");
           System.out.println("====================");
           System.out.println("1 - End Program");
           System.out.println("2 - Add Fruit");
           System.out.println("3 - Remove Fruit");
           System.out.println("4 - Modify Fruit");
           System.out.println("5 - List of your fruit");

           int choice = chris.nextInt();

                switch(choice){
                    case 1:
                        loops = false;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        addfruit();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        removefruit();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        modifyfruit(option, fruits);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        printlist();
                        break;
                    default:
                        printlist();
                        System.out.println("***PLEASE SELECT FROM THE LIST***");
                        break;

            }

        }

    }
    public static void printlist(){
        System.out.println("Your list of furit");
        System.out.println(charles);
    }
    public static void addfruit(){
        System.out.println("Add another fruit");
        String trees = chris.next();
        charles.add(trees);
        System.out.println("You've successfully added "+trees);
        printlist();

    }
        public static void removefruit(){
        System.out.println("Select what fruit to remove");
        int removal = chris.nextInt();
        charles.remove(removal-1);
        System.out.println("You've successfully added "+removal);
        printlist();

    }
        public static void modifyfruit(int option, String fruits){
        System.out.println("Select what position to change");
        option = chris.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Select A new fruit to add");
        fruits = chris.next();
        charles.set(option+1, fruits);
        System.out.println("Your new fruit is "+ fruits);
        printlist();

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message? What part don't you understand?

Comment: I figured it out. I really didn't need any arguments in my method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need arguments in you `modifyfruit`method. Remove them where you invoke the method and in the method signature and just define them within the method.

```
    public static void modifyfruit() {
        System.out.println("Select what position to change");
        int option = chris.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Select A new fruit to add");
        String fruits = chris.next();
        charles.set(option + 1, fruits);
        System.out.println("Your new fruit is " + fruits);
        printlist();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you sir, that was the issue. There was a huge brain freeze on that lol

Answer (score -1):

Inside the switch:

```
case 4:
                    modifyfruit(option, fruits);
                    break;
```

option and fruits are yet not created, Can see that when you are defining the method modifyfruit() option and fruits are being taken input from user.